# TypeScript React: How do you pass a generic to a React.ComponentProps<typeof ComponentWithGenericProps>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## Context

I have a `Tree` component and its props are defined using a generic type `T`:

```
type ITreeProps<T> = ICollapsibleTreeProps<T> | INonCollapsibleTreeProps<T>;
```

My component is defined as so:

```
const Tree = <T extends {}>(props: ITreeProps<T>) => { /* ... */ };
```

## Problem

Now if I create a `type` using `React.ComponentProps` (in a separate file importing the `Tree` component)

```
type ITreeComponentProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Tree>;
```

The generic is automatically considered as `{}`, so the resulting type is:

```
type ITreeComponentProps = ICollapsibleTreeProps<{}> | INonCollapsibleTreeProps<{}>
```

## Question

Is there a way to pass a generic to `React.ComponentProps` so I can specify my own type instead of having it forced to `{}`?

my intuition was then to do the following, which **does not work**, although I expected the generic type to come without having to specify a `T`:

```
type ITreeComponentProps<T> = (React.ComponentProps<typeof Tree>)<T>;
```

with the resulting type being

```
type ITreeComponentProps<T> = ICollapsibleTreeProps<T> | INonCollapsibleTreeProps<T>
```

So I can use it as so:

```
const someFunction = <T extends {}>(p: ITreeComponentProps<T>) => { /* ... */ };
```

## Temporary Solution

Until I find the solution, the only way I can use it as the last snippet is to export the `ITreeProps` and import it in my other file instead of using `React.ComponentProps`. However, I don't usually like exporting my component props as a personal preference.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I adopted the same solution as you, but I don't quite like. Did you find out how to do this using `React.ComponentProps`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Unless I'm missing something, this seems to be a TypeScript limitation... I am still using the exported type from my component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `typeof Tree<Foo>`

This is not possible in TypeScript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/204

TL;DR `typeof` works with values and `Tree<Foo>` is a type, despite that `Tree` itself is a value.

P.S: we're also using types exported along with components

P.P.S: here is the maintainers discouraging usage of React.ComponentProps https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/34899#issuecomment-485815000